# how to get value inside node

Tags: c++, rapidxml

if i have xml content

```
<aaa> 1111<bbb>222</bbb>333 </aaa>
```

Then how to get value which is "1111" and "333"

but I only can get value of first node which is "1111" only

Please advise

code is here

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidxml/rapidxml.hpp"
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidxml;

string content = "<aaa> 1112<bbb>222</bbb>333 </aaa>";

int main(int argc, char**argv) {


    xml_document<> m_doc;

    try {

        m_doc.parse<0>(&content[0]);

    } catch (rapidxml::parse_error &error) {
        cout <<"parse_error\n";
        exit(1);

    }

     xml_node<>* node = m_doc.first_node();
     cout << "name = " <<node->name()<<endl;
     cout << "value = "<< node->value() <<endl;
     cout << "value_size = "<< node->value_size()<<endl;

    m_doc.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
name = aaa
value =  1111
value_size = 5
```

Comment: never used that library before, but something tells me you should get what you want by cycling on the node list using `xml_node::next_sibling`(see tutorial at http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#classrapidxml_1_1xml__node).

Comment: @didierc using next_sibling , will get NULL point back , coz there is no sibling node

Answer (score 0):

Use next_sibling function to find the next string under same node.
Same is used by Xerces library to find the next string under same node.

Comment: using next_sibling , will get NULL point back , coz there is no sibling node

Comment: DOMNode *domNodeP = GetDOMElement()->getFirstChild();


while(domNodeP != NULL && domNodeP->getNodeType() != DOMNode::ELEMENT_NODE) {
        domNodeP = domNodeP->getNextSibling();
    }

i used the above code for xerces to find the next sibling under any node like <aa>xyz
lmn
</aa> and this return me lmn.
I think You should also try the same get the first child and then iterate through the node to find the next sibling(for text)

Answer (score 0):

Good question : I'd initially misread the XML structure you're trying to parse.

I haven't tried this, but I think that once you have found the first node `<aaa>` you must then get the first child node (which should have type `node_data`, value `1111` in your example.) , rather than getting the value of the `node_element`.

Then iterate over all it's siblings looking for other nodes with type `node_data`.